# Can I form a new lattice basis from an old by adding multiples of $(1,1,1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $B=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3),(b_1,b_2,b_3)\}$ is a lattice basis for the kernel of some linear transformation $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^3$, is $B^{*}=\{(a_1+k,a_2+k,a_3+k),(b_1+k,b_2+k,b_3+k)\}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ also a basis?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. This is the same as asking: If I add $(1,1,1)$ to $b \in B$ ($k$-many times), do I remain in $B$? Take $B=ker((1,2,3))=\mathbb{Z}\{(2,-1,0),(3,0,-1)\}$. Then $(4,1,2)=(2,-1,0)+2(1,1,1) \not\in B$.